# I can't receive a sent bitcoin yet

Tags: blockchain

Some body sent me 0.55 bitcoins on the 29/12/2016 and i have not recieved it uptil now and the coins have been deducted from the sender's wallet. Is it normal to experience this kind of issues?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it first thing check the bitcoin address from your sender and check your bitcoin address too if they are both the same and correct. If correct and until now you haven't receive it means the bitcoin network is still processing your bitcoin to your address. Every transaction goes to block chain. If you have copy of block chain process you can check it out to monitor the activity to your bitcoin.

You will receive it after the chain is complete. Thanks!

For more info go here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_chain

Comment: Is it normal for the processing to reach up to 24 hrs

Comment: Have you ever experienced such before